# How to make a multilevel context menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a custom context menu here is my code . Here i want to add a multilevel custom context.

[img]https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeGhf.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjXnF.jpg

I have tried appending two li tags here

var view = d3.select('#contextMenuNode')

view.html(`<li><a id="selectLinked1" tabindex="-1" href=#>View A</a></li> <li><a id="selectLinked2" tabindex="-1" href=#>View B</a></li>`)

Comment: please provide your code in your question not the reference only that you want to implement.

Comment: I am just appending two li tags whenever i am doing a right click on the svg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Show contextmenu:
  $(document).contextmenu(function(e) {
    //Get window size:
    var winWidth = $(document).width();
    var winHeight = $(document).height();
    //Get pointer position:
    var posX = e.pageX;
    var posY = e.pageY;
    //Get contextmenu size:
    var menuWidth = $(".contextmenu").width();
    var menuHeight = $(".contextmenu").height();
    //Security margin:
    var secMargin = 10;
    //Prevent page overflow:
    if (posX + menuWidth + secMargin >= winWidth &&
      posY + menuHeight + secMargin >= winHeight) {
      //Case 1: right-bottom overflow:
      posLeft = posX - menuWidth - secMargin + "px";
      posTop = posY - menuHeight - secMargin + "px";
    } else if (posX + menuWidth + secMargin >= winWidth) {
      //Case 2: right overflow:
      posLeft = posX - menuWidth - secMargin + "px";
      posTop = posY + secMargin + "px";
    } else if (posY + menuHeight + secMargin >= winHeight) {
      //Case 3: bottom overflow:
      posLeft = posX + secMargin + "px";
      posTop = posY - menuHeight - secMargin + "px";
    } else {
      //Case 4: default values:
      posLeft = posX + secMargin + "px";
      posTop = posY + secMargin + "px";
    };
    //Display contextmenu:
    $(".contextmenu").css({
      "left": posLeft,
      "top": posTop
    }).show();
    //Prevent browser default contextmenu.
    return false;
  });
  //Hide contextmenu:
  $(document).click(function() {
    $(".contextmenu").hide();
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #DCE775;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
}

h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 1em;
  font-size: 2em;
  letter-spacing: .3em;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 2px solid #E6EE9C;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #E6EE9C;
}

.contextmenu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 5px;
  list-style: none;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 35px rgba(50, 50, 90, 0.1), 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
  z-index: 999999;
}

.contextmenu li {
  border-left: 3px solid transparent;
  transition: ease .2s;
}

.contextmenu li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #B0BEC5;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: ease .2s;
}

.contextmenu li:hover {
  background: #CE93D8;
  border-left: 3px solid #9C27B0;
}

.contextmenu li:hover a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.submenu {
  display: none;
}

li:hover .submenu {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 200px;
  right: -200px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0;
}

.submenu li {
  list-style: none;
  color: #B0BEC5;
}

.submenu li a {
  color: #B0BEC5 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Right click!</h1>

<ul class="contextmenu">
  <li><a href="#">Hover Me</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">3</a></li>

    </ul>

  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Link to somewhere</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Another link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link to nowhere</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Random link</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Google Fonts -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Glad that helped.

Comment: only thing is why there is a gap between the submenu , its showing a gap

Comment: That because i forget to add padding: 0; to the second ul. i have update the snippet.